# Submenu going out of scope

Tags: jquery, html, css

image link - http://i64.tinypic.com/30kzzn4.jpg

The sub menu of the navigation goes beyond browser border.
as it is in the image. i have tired of working on it now if somebody can help it would be great.

Edit - "Here is my site url - http://103.9.168.2/~wwwhotelhomecom/quote/"

Comment: where are your code ? please insert code in jsfiddle

Comment: try style in submenu with ## position: absolute; and ##  right: 0

Comment: @Sumitpatel I have posted my website url,

Comment: Also your navbar is not responsive.

Comment: I want it to be like sm menu http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/